# How to parse json to enum from different sources

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm getting data in json format from different sources and I'm trying to map them to objects implementing the same interface.

The json variable looks something like this from feed 1:

```
{"identifier": 232, "type": "Feed1"}
```

And I'm serializing it using this object:

```
   [DataContract]
    public class Class A : InterfaceA
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "identifier")]
        public int Id{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public FeedType Type { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public enum FeedType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "Feed1")]
        FeedA,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Feed2")]
        FeedB,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Feed3")]
        FeedC
    }
```

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface InterfaceA
{
   int Id {get;set;}
   FeedType Type{get;set;}
}
```

In feed 2, the object looks like this:

```
{"identifier": 232, "feedType": "A"}
```

How can I create another object that implements the same interface and will return the same enum? How do I set up the DataContract?

EDIT:

I serialize it like this

```
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(ClassA);

            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
            var serializedObject = serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

Comment: first things first, you cannot create an instance of an interface so you will need to create an instance of an actual class, have you thought about using a generic method?

Comment: Can you include the code where you actually seralize the Json too?

Comment: @Liam I did think about generic types. But I would like it to be the same type of enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give an answer using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (of course if you are open to use a different serializer)

```
string json = @"{""identifier"": 232, ""type"": ""Feed2""}";
var classa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassA>(json);
```

.

```
public interface InterfaceA
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    FeedType Type { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))] //<--- !!!
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public FeedType Type { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public enum FeedType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Feed1")]
    FeedA,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Feed2")]
    FeedB,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Feed3")]
    FeedC
}
```

And this is the type converter class

```
public class MyConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(FeedType);
    }


    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var field = objectType.GetFields()
            .First(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                         .Any(a=>a.GetType()==typeof(EnumMemberAttribute) &&
                                 ((EnumMemberAttribute)a).Value.Equals(reader.Value))); 



        return field.GetValue(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly like that, but I would prefer not having to swith serializer

Comment: @johan As you can see it gives much more control over serialization/deserialization process than other serializers. (BTW MVC4 also uses it).

Comment: Well, since I'm not getting any other answer I guess is the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so if you want a class B

```
[DataContract]
    public class ClassB : InterfaceA
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "identifier")]
        public int Id{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public FeedType Type { get; set; }
    }

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(ClassB);

            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
            var serializedObject = serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

Thats it?! you could use a generic if you wanted to reuse the code:

```
public T SerialiseObject<T>(string json) where T : InterfaceA
{
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(T);

var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
 return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

then call it:

```
SerialiseObject<ClassA>(json);
SerialiseObject<ClassB>(json);
```

**to explain more fully** you could not have

```
public class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
 public ns1.FeedType Type{get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB : InterfaceA
{
  public ns2.FeedType Type{get; set;}
}
```

this would not compile as `InterfaceA` would expect either `ns1.FeedType` or `ns2.FeedType`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that answers my question. How would that serialize "feedType" in the second json response correctly to the enum?

Comment: FeedType would be the same type in both? It'd need to be or else it would break the interface declaration?

Comment: I understand that fully. But you solution wouldn't work as the json looks different. What you explain as not a funtional solution would work if the interface uses generic types.